# moving task of subtype ListEmail from one contact to another using apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

We are trying to move a task from one contact to another in a trigger. the task is created by ListEmail functionality.

We are getting an exception if re-assigning the WhoId. Exception:

Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00T1N00002TXv3jUAD; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Related To ID: id value of incorrect type: 0XB1N000000XaCuWAK: [WhatId]

This is the sample code:

```
List<Task> task = [SELECT Id, RecordTypeId, WhoId, WhoCount, WhatCount, Subject, AccountId, TaskSubtype, AccountId__c, EmailListWhatID__c FROM Task where Id ='00T1N00002TXv3jUAD'];

system.debug('task = ' + task);
Task tk = task.get(0);
tk.WhoId = '0031N00001UvZDpQAN';
database.update(tk);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the exception relates to the WhatId, I suspect that whatever the custom object type referred to by the prefix 0XB is, it does not have Allow Activities active on the object metadata.

Comment: There is no custom object involved here. the 0XB1N000000XaCuWAK belongs to ListEmail and Activities are allowed on it.